# Calling source within a function - scoping issue

Tags: r, environment

I am trying to solve this scoping issue within function call. Function `Perform` throws an error. To be exact, error is `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'a' not found`. Calling source within a function within another function is the issue (i.e., object `a` is not available to `CallScript` function inside `Perform` function). `Perforxm1` is fine - so I want to understand how to fix `Perform` function. (`Add_a_b.R` file is a script with just `a+b` for testing purposes). Thanks in advance.

```
CallScript<-function(ii){
  source(ii,echo = T,local=T)
}

Perform<-function(a,b){
  ii<-'~/Test/Add_a_b.R'
  CallScript(ii)
}

Perform1<-function(a,b){
  ii<-'~/Test/Add_a_b.R'
  source(ii,echo = T,local=T)
}

Perform(a=10,b=15)
Perform1(a=10,b=15)
```

Comment: Try using the fully qualified path to the R script, starting at root `/`.

Comment: The file name is okay (the same format executes in the `Perform1` function). The issue is scoping. I want to know how to reference the `perform`'s environment, so `CallScript` function can find `a` in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was playing with some options and found out a fix for the problem. But I am still lacking the understanding. So I am documenting my findings for different scenarios here. Hope this helps people!

```
# To call within another function, reference enclosing environment!!
# Fixed my problem.
# Is there any other methods to achieve this?
CallScript<-function(ii){
  source(ii,echo = T, local=parent.frame())
}

Perform<-function(a,b){
  ii<-'~/Test/Add_a_b.R'
  CallScript(ii)
}

Perform(a=10,b=15)


# Using local=T or local=environment() options don't work in this scenario!
CallScript<-function(ii){
  source(ii,echo = T, local=T)
  #source(ii,echo = T, local=environment())
}    
Perform<-function(a,b){
  ii<-'~/Test/Add_a_b.R'
  CallScript(ii)
}    
Perform(a=10,b=15)


# I also found out that these also work.
Perform_env<-function(a,b){
  ii<-'~/Test/Add_a_b.R'
  source(ii,echo = T,local=environment())
}

Perform_loc<-function(a,b){
  ii<-'~/Test/Add_a_b.R'
  source(ii,echo = T,local=T)
}
Perform_env(a=10,b=15)
Perform_loc(a=10,b=15)


# But this doesn't work
Perform_par<-function(a,b){
  ii<-'~/Test/Add_a_b.R'
  source(ii,echo = T,local=parent.frame())
}
Perform_par(a=10,b=15)
```

To complicate things, here is another scenario. Except `local=F`, all three options work in this scenario.

```
# CallScript defined within `Perform` function.
Perform<-function(a,b){
  CallScript<-function(ii){
    # parent.frame works
    #source(ii,echo = T,local=parent.frame())

    # environment works
    #source(ii,echo = T,local=environment())

    # Local=T also work
    source(ii,echo = T,local=T)
  }

  ii<-'~/Test/Add_a_b.R'
  CallScript(ii)
}

Perform(a=10,b=15)
```

With @MrFlick's suggestion, this is also working:

```
CallScript<-function(ii){
  a <- get("a", parent.frame())
  b <- get("b", parent.frame())
  source(ii,echo = T, local=T)
}

Perform<-function(a,b){
  ii<-'~/Test/Add_a_b.R'
  CallScript(ii)
}

Perform(a=10,b=15)
```

Comment: So which part of your solution are you unsure about? Your change to `CallScript()` in the first code block was right. You need to use `parent.frame()` so it can find `a` and `b` from the functions that call it. This has to do with R's lexicographical scoping.

Comment: Also it would make a lot more sense to use `source()` to load proper functions. Then you can call these functions in your own code. Loading raw expressions probably isn't a long-term good design decision.

Comment: My scenario is, I have many small code snippets that I copy-paste into a folder for each project and then tinker with variable names, function definitions,  other arguments, specific to that project & scenario (I don't want to maintain a library to match all scenarios). So I call the snippets by `CallScript` function. The snippets do have functions. So I use kinda nested `source` within `source`.

Comment: R's a functional language. It would be way easier to just make proper functions. But if you insist on using source like this, then just be aware that's not how R expects it to be used so you're going to have to be very careful with environments and scoping.

Comment: Is it possible to specify the `Perform` function's environment along this lines? 
`CallScript<-function(ii){
  a <- get("a", environment());
  source(ii,echo = T, local=T);
}`

Comment: You’d have to pass it in as a parameter to CallScript.

Comment: I am not sure what to pass as a parameter. Environment or arguments (e.g. `a`, `b`)?

Comment: In a perfect world you would just have a function that uses parameters a and b but you seem to want to pass environments around which is not very R like. Have you read this yet? It might help you. http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html